# Input type number with background white under arrows

Tags: css, input, numbers

I am trying to create an input of type number with a background of white under the arrows. I have looked all over and cannot find a way to change this via CSS.  Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: You should provide any research you've done, and/or what you've *attempted* and how you *failed*

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have some JS involved in order to do this.  You'll need to replace the default arrows and replace them with something you can style.  Look at this example:

```js
jQuery('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">+</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">-</div></div>').insertAfter('.quantity input');
    jQuery('.quantity').each(function() {
      var spinner = jQuery(this),
        input = spinner.find('input[type="number"]'),
        btnUp = spinner.find('.quantity-up'),
        btnDown = spinner.find('.quantity-down'),
        min = input.attr('min'),
        max = input.attr('max');

      btnUp.click(function() {
        var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
        if (oldValue >= max) {
          var newVal = oldValue;
        } else {
          var newVal = oldValue + 1;
        }
        spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
        spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
      });

      btnDown.click(function() {
        var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
        if (oldValue <= min) {
          var newVal = oldValue;
        } else {
          var newVal = oldValue - 1;
        }
        spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
        spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
      });

    });
```

```css
.quantity {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number]
{
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.quantity input {
  width: 45px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  
}

.quantity input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.quantity-nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
}

.quantity-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  line-height: 1.7;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-up {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background: yellow;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <input type="number" step="1" value="1">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I ended up doing since I could not find a simple solution and I already had the  logic for zooming in place.  Thank you for your assist.